# getting Ajax href location using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Let's say I have this function:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr, settings){
    });
```

And I want to get the loaded document location, I tried looking for it in the xhr object, but I can't seem to find where the url of the loaded page is, please note - I don't want the document.location.href but the xhr href.

Comment: RTFM http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/ =p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `settings` argument contains all the options that were used for the AJAX call including the url:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr, settings){
    alert(settings.url);
});
```